# Can i use mysql as database for android chat app?

Tags: android, mysql

I want to build chatting app using android studio. I am having trouble choosing database for my chat app. My question is can i use mysql as database for my chat application?

Comment: If you are asking for app level database then you can't and if asking for server level, choose anything

Comment: mysql is not that great when it comes to chat app i suggest you to use sendbird or firebase if targeting a chat app

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql database using the server with REST API . For Android App you can use the sqlite for storing data but for communication with other user you require some server with will communicate to another user. you can refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP, mostly all app use this protocol for chat purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql-lite or SnappyDB  Here's [a link](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB)  . SnappyDB is best ,its light wait, it can store json also

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.